# Geometric Distribution find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n n$$ where $$\pi_n=p^n(1-p)$$

Can somebody help me out?

I tried differentiating (but there is an extra factor $1-p$.

Comment: Hint:  The $(1-p)$ just factors out, so your expression is $(1-p)\times \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\,p^n$.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was obvious :)

Comment: You might want to factor this like $p(1-p)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty np^{n-1}$ Then $np^{n-1}$ looks like the derivative of something common.